# Efficient way to get nodes X level deep

Tags: dataset, umbraco, webforms

I have a 4 levels deep node structure, where the top most level is made of 1 root node.

What I want to do is get all nodes in the 4th level for which a certain property(ies) is true, for example:

get all 4th level nodes where nodePropertyX == true.

Now, I could do this with a for-each loop, and iterate all the items in the levels above, but I have the feeling it would be inefficient.

1. How can I do it in a better more efficient way ? Is there a way to maybe cache my dataset? (I'm returning results as a datatable) ?
2. What is the preferrable method: using C# control (.ascx) or razor script (.cshtml)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with those nodes, you may use **razor**, **macros** and the built-in caching abilities for macros to **cache the output of the macro**:

Here's how to get all nodes at the 4th level from the root node having a property *nodePropertyX* which equals *value* :

```
@foreach (var item in @Model.AncestorOrSelf().Descendants()
    .Where("Visible")
    .Where("level=4")
    .Where("nodePropertyX == \"value\""))
{
    <a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a>
}
```

Place this code in a *Scripting file* (Section *Developer*, node *Scripting Files*), create a macro using this scripting file, and insert the macro wherever (on any template) you want to display the list of those nodes.

In order to **cache the output of the macro**, select the macro and set the appropriate properties (*Cache Period*, *Cache By Page* and *Cache Personalized*).

Comment: Will that scan the entire content tree (albeit cached)? You could write your own recursive method that will not scan below level 4